# Numpy saving big ints as floats

Tags: numpy

I am having trouble with numpy saving large ints as floats. Here's a simple example, first I make a numpy array of large ints.

```python
from random import randint
import numpy as np

min_int = 182_134_926_853_412_476
rand_big_ints = [randint(min_int, 2 * min_int) for _ in range(10)]
np_rand_big_ints = np.array(rand_big_ints)
```

I check that these are ints

```
array([252684792489159497, 247692926601611023, 223174123368132841,
       255596017185852990, 318647893588684448, 331851729687912180,
       191223276914989801, 239394981298569364, 199835758154280122,
       313714064550926566], dtype=int64)
```

Then I save them using numpy's `savetxt` function

```python
np.savetxt('rand_big_ints.csv', np_rand_big_ints, delimiter=',')
```

But when I examine the resulting CSV the big ints have been rendered as floats in the CSV, losing information.

```
2.526847924891594880e+17
2.476929266016110080e+17
2.231741233681328320e+17
2.555960171858529920e+17
3.186478935886844160e+17
3.318517296879121920e+17
1.912232769149897920e+17
2.393949812985693760e+17
1.998357581542801280e+17
3.137140645509265920e+17
```

I can work around this, by converting the array to a pandas Series and then saving it, but how would I get numpy to honour the 'type' and not render big ints as floats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify an integer format:

```
np.savetxt('rand_big_ints.csv', np_rand_big_ints, fmt='%d', delimiter=',')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to format the values as strings

```
np.savetxt('rand_big_ints.csv', np_rand_big_ints.astype(str), fmt='"%s"', delimiter=',')
```

`fmt='%s'` also works if you view the file as text, but spreadsheet tools don't support big int so they'll again truncate the values to float

Comment: With Excel, you can stop it changing big ints to floats in the data import dialog. I use that trick lots.